# wordpress redirect error in xampp

Tags: redirect, xampp

i had a wordpress website on xampp let's say in "localhost/listing" and it was working perfectly 
then i installed another copy of this website on "localhost/mylisting" now the problem is that when i type "localhost/listing/wp-admin" the site redirects itself to "localhost/mylisting/wp-admin"
i dont know how to solve this problem.
i tried making another directory and copying all contents on listing in it and the problem was same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your new copy of the site `localhost/mylisting` is still hooked into same database as `localhost/listing`.

So to avoid that, you have to point your new installation to a different database. to do that, goto your phpmyadmin and export your current db, then create new empty db and import into it. then goto newly imported db's wp-options table. change siteURL and homepage URL to `localhost/mylisting` from `localhost/listing`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the site url and home url.The problem is database have the old url address thats why you are facing this problem. You can use this code in wp-config file and change url accordingly.

define('WP_HOME','http://example');

define('WP_SITEURL','http://example');

define('RELOCATE',true);